# Fragment, getArguments =null, обмен между фрагментами

Tags: android

При попытке обмена данными между фрагментами или при передаче из activity в фрагмент, `getArguments` всегда возвращает `null`. Причина лично мне непонятна.

Код активити:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
}
  public void OnClick(View view)
{
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button:
        {

            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container,new fragment2());
            new fragment2().newInstance(10);
            break;
        }
    }
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Код фрагмента:

```
  public class fragment2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
  {

  public static fragment2 newInstance(int columnCount) {
    fragment2 fragment = new fragment2();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("ARG_COLUMN_COUNT", columnCount);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View viewFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);



    if (getArguments() != null)
    {
        int a = getArguments().getInt("ARG_COLUMN_COUNT");
    }  else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No getArguments", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return viewFragment;
}
```

Соответственно всегда возвращается `getArguments() == null`. Подскажите почему он возвращается? Нигде внятного решения не нашёл.
Спасибо.

Comment: при таком коде ваш `fragment2` вообще не должен нигде отображаться по идее. Имена классов в Java принято писать с большой буквы, вроде мелочь, а читать ваш код весьма трудно, если публикуете код, уважайте других программистов и придерживайтесь конвенции Java.

Comment: Это пробный код, поэтому имена такие . И почему фрагмент не должен нигде отображаться?

Comment: Не работает все равно. То были хвосты из предыдущих попыток. Поэтому и поубирал, что бы не смущали никого. С этого момента поподробнее пожалуйста. Не понял.

Comment: Если правильно понял, то создается два экземпляра. И один из них как раз и возвращает null. Как же всё упаковать в один? Понял :)   fragment2 frag2 = new fragment2();
             fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container,frag2.newInstance(10));

Comment: Неправильно вы все поняли, экземпляр создается инстансом и не надо его создавать перед вызовом инстанса. Смотрите [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554013/177345). Так же прочитайте, что нужно делать, когда [кто то ответил на ваш вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), это же касается и других ваших вопросов, неужели не один из ответов на них не решил вашей проблемы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы прикрепляете к разметке один экземпляр класса `fragment2` без вызова инстанса и соответственно, без вызова `setArguments()`. Другой экземпляр, с вызовом инстанса, просто болтается "в воздухе" нигде не отображаясь.

Вызывайте фрагмент с инстансом так:

```
fragment2 fragment = fragment2.newInstance(10);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
```

Эту строку уберите вовсе:

```
new fragment2().newInstance(10);
```

смотрите [этот официальный гайд](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)  по работе с фрагментами, где в том числе есть и способ [с передачей аргументов через инстанс](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#BackStack).

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы мне помогли!